# Exclude conditionally a meta key from meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have in the Wordpress *functions.php* the next code that changes the `main_query` when posts are sorted using a form. **The question is**: how to exclude from the `main_query` the second array of the `meta_query` when the *$country* variable is empty?

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby || $order || $country ) ) {
    if ( in_array( $orderby, array( 'event_start_date' ) ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', $order );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the events after today's date
            array(
                'key'         => 'event_start_date', // Check the start date field
                'value'       => date_i18n("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                'compare'     => '>=', // Return the ones greater than or equal to today's date
                'type'        => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with date
            ),
            array(
                'key'         => 'venue_country',
                'value'       => $country,
            )
        ) );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

A suggestion how to solve this I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24715159/1354580).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in this way:

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby || $order || $country ) ) {
    if ( in_array( $orderby, array( 'event_start_date' ) ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', $order );
        if( !empty( $_GET['country'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $metaquery1 );
        } else {
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $metaquery2 );
        }
    }
}
```